# How does the sound of a tuning fork depend on the size of a tuning fork?

Tags: waves, acoustics, frequency

The pitch of a note is how high or low it sounds. The pitch of a note depends on the frequency, or the number of vibrations each second. 
If you listen to the notes produced by a loudspeaker connected to a signal generator you notice that, as the frequency increases, the pitch gets higher.

This is all the information I've got for the time being.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make the tines of a tuning fork longer it will take more time for the forces in the metal to change the direction of their movement, so the frequency will be lower and they will sound a lower note.